# I cannot find SQL Server browser

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2017, sqlbrowser

I have installed SQL SERVER 17.

I'm trying to connect to a remote Database and I was not able to do so. After research, I found out that it requires the SQL Server Browser service to be started but I couldn't find the service in the SQL Server Configuration Manager

[image: SQL Server Configuration Manager]
I also tried searching for missing SQL Browser Service. So, I tried reinstalling the SSMS but I couldn't find any option to select for SQL Browser.
 Also, I don't have the sqlbrowser.exe file at location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\'. So, I guess it wasn't installed from the start.

[image: sqlsever.exe not found]

Any solution, on how to install the service?

**EDIT 1 :**
This is the error message on the SSMS:
[image: SSMS Error Message]

I have verified and made sure that the username and password is correct.

**EDIT 2 :**
I tried to turn of my firewall and then connect with the server. But, I still got the same error.
So, I tried to reinstall the complete SQL SERVER. During the installation, I selected the custom mode and selected the SQL Server Browser to be automatic. So, now I have it working.
[image]

Now, still having my firewall disabled, I tried connecting to the SERVER, but still I got the same error.
Now the question is why am I getting this error?

**Final EDIT :**
Sorry for all the trouble but I have posted the answer to the problem, Thanks.

Comment: It is not a SSMS service, it must be installed and opened (firewall) on the SERVER you connect to.

Comment: @TomTom It is installed and opened on SERVER

Comment: Can this be due to firewall on my machine side?

Comment: what is the error message when you try to connect?

Comment: @nazimhatipoglu I have edited the question and added the error message screenshot.

Comment: check image link pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really sorry for the trouble.

And the problem was a slash ( \ ).

I spent couple of hours trying to figure out what's wrong with the connection and all that time I used **SERVER / INSTANCENAME** and everything else was perfect... and suddenly when I was searching online someone had made a same mistake and I looked at my hostname and it was wrong.
It should be **SERVER \ INSTANCENAME** with a backslash ( \ ).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to install SQL browser to simply connect to a remote database, it allows you to see SQL server instances on your machine.

In management studio, adding the hostname and credentials in the connection dialog box is enough and if they are correct, and you have access, it will connect.

Comment: More exact: it requires SQL Browser installed ON THE SERVER YOU CONNECT TO. And the firewall to be opened etc.

Comment: I have the hostname, the instance name, and the valid credentials. Still, I am not able to connect to that instance. Whereas, I had tried the same procedure in a different machine before and it had worked correctly.

Comment: @TomTom I guess the Server has the SQL Browser, because I was able to connect to it using a different machine before.